# Adding itextg to gradle

Tags: android, itext, android-gradle-plugin, itextg

I want to add itextg via gradle to avoid having to maintain a set of library jars. Maybe it's me but I can't find the correct gradle compile statement anywhere.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.itextg:itextg:5.4.3'
}
```

Regular itext works just fine but I'm trying to do stuff with images.

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf-5.5.6'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>I think that's because we released **iText** as a `jar` on [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.6) (which Gradle also uses as a repository) and also as a download from various sites ([GitHub](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/releases), SourceForge); but **iTextG** only as a download on various sites, not on Maven Central. iTextG uses the same namespace as iText: `com.itextpdf:itextpdf` so having it on Maven Central too would create conflicts. Something like `com.itextg:itextg` simply does not exist *(as far as I know - and I am supposed to know because I am QA Engineer at iText Software)*.
In fact, the main difference between iText and iTextG, is that we have stripped all AWT dependencies from iTextG. For the rest they are exactly the same codebase.</s>

So, to finally answer your question after all this background information: you'll have to download the [iTextG](http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg) `jar` and manually add it to your `libs` folder.

As of iText `5.5.9`, you can add this to your Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I did and while it's not ideal for maintenance purposes, I surmise that there are no plans to change this in the near future so I'll just deal with it. Thanks!

Comment: Feedback is always welcome! iTextG is not a separate product, it is a stripped down version of iText (AWT references removed). Indeed no plans to change this in iText 5.x

Comment: You will be glad to hear that I am currently working on getting a mavenized version of iTextG. To be expected for version 5.5.9, to be released later this month.

Comment: As of `5.5.9`, you can use Gradle as the OP intended. There is an artifact `com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9`. Previous versions will not be uploaded to Maven Central, since we haven't seen that specific request from our customers. See http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextg/5.5.9 for the artifact.

Comment: I tried adding 5.5.11 but did not work, 5.5.9 it is. works like a charm

Comment: Just wait a bit for 5.5.11, I know it's behind a bit but it will arrive soon enough.